# Half Bridge Bootstrap configuration using IR2184 Gate Driver

Tags: inverter, gate-driving, igbt, tesla-coil, bootstrap

I am planning on building a half bridge inverter for use as a tesla coil driver, using a couple of IGBTs, with gates driven by an IR2184 half bridge gate driver. According to the data-sheet, the typical connection is as follows:

[image]

However simplified half-bridge schematics all across the internet have a different configuration with the  source of the high-side switch connected to the drain of the low-side switch, accompanied by a couple of capacitors across the load as follows:

[image]

I understand how the second configuration works, but I'm lost as to how the 'Typical Connection' as provided by the IR2184 datasheet would create an AC voltage across the load.

I've made this schematic which blends the two above, but I wanted to check if this would work, or is there some function of the IR2184 that I'm missing that allows it to work in the first connection.

[image]

Not new to electronics, but very new to gate drivers, half-bridges etc, so any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The schematic looks correct. But placing equal resistors across C2 and C4 guarantees equal drop across them. The resistances should be low enough to discharge the capacitors quickly when you turn the system off, and high enough to keep the wasted power low. 470k can be a starting value.

Comment: Did the circuit shown above work well?
Was the ground of the driver connected to the ground of the half bridge driver? I am rectifying mains AC to DC which is fed into my half bridge inverter, was there any problem that you encountered with isolation? Kind Regards